# Count number of Distinct days in query

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

We have a table that has a `StartDate` field which holds a type of datetime.  There are thousands of records and I am looking for a way to find the number of days within a given result returned from this table.  For instance, if my table had this data:

```
ID | StartDate
--------------
1   01/01/2013 09:34:54
2   01/01/2013 11:23:21
3   04/11/2013 14:43:23
4   04/11/2013 17:13:03
5   04/25/2013 18:02:59
6   07/21/2013 02:56:12
7   10/01/2013 19:43:10
```

Then the query should return **5** as the 2 dates on 01/01/2013 count as 1 and the same for 04/11/2013.

The only SQL I've been able to come up with is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(DATEPART(DAY, StartDate)))
FROM Stats
WHERE StartDate BETWEEN '01/01/2013' AND '12/31/2013' --This is just for filtering
```

But this returns **4** because it doesn't take the month into account.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can `CAST` as date

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(StartDate AS DATE))
FROM   Stats
WHERE  StartDate >= '20130101' AND StartDate < '20140101'
```

Also use an unambiguous date format such as `yyyymmdd` and `>= <` not `BETWEEN`.

Your current query would include the 31st December if there was a row with exactly the value `20131231 00:00:00` but not any with different times on that date. I doubt that is intentional.